# How to get a link in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hyperlink

with attached screenshot my question can be explained quite well.
[image: Screenshot]

I am **scraping** the following page: https://www.transfermarkt.de/tsg-1899-hoffenheim/kader/verein/533/saison_id/2019/plus/1

Table 1 lists the team. In the second column is the player. I need the link as you can see in the screenshot on the bottom left.

When I look into the data frame normally, I only get the following in this cell: "Oliver BaumannO. BaumannTorwart" But I am looking for "https://www.transfermarkt.de/oliver-baumann/profil/spieler/55089".

You guys got any ideas?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# Global variables
HEADS = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'}
dateiname = 'test.xlsx'
# Global variables

def get_response(url):
   # URL-Anfrage durchfuehren    
   try:
      response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADS)
    
   except AttributeError:
      print('AttributeError') 

   return response


def scraping_kader(response): 
   try:
       dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)
       #dfs = dfs.to_html(escape=False)
       print(dfs[1])
       print(dfs[1].iloc[0, :])

   except ImportError:
       print(' ImportError')
    
   except ValueError:
       print(' ValueError')
    
   except AttributeError:
       print(' AttributeError') 

    
response = get_response('https://www.transfermarkt.de/tsg-1899-hoffenheim/kader/verein/533/saison_id/2019/plus/1')

scraping_kader(response)
```

Comment: if page use javaScript to generate date then you will need Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript. `requests`/`pandas`/`beautifulsoup`/`lxml` can't run JavaScript.

Comment: as I know pandas gets only text form table and you may need `beautifulsoup`/`lxml` to works more manually with HTML and get links.

Answer (score 1):

as I know `read_html` gets only text from table and it doesn't care of links, hidden elements, attributes, etc.

You need module like `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to work with full HTML and manually get needed information.

```
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
   
   all_tooltips = soup.find_all('td', class_='hauptlink')
   
   for item in all_tooltips:
       item = item.find('a', class_='spielprofil_tooltip')
       if item:
           print(item['href']) #, item.text)
```

This example gets only links but in the same way you can get other elements.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import pandas as pd

HEADS = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_response(url):
   try:
      response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADS)
   except AttributeError:
      print('AttributeError') 

   return response

def scraping_kader(response): 
   try:
       soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
       
       all_tooltips = soup.find_all('td', class_='hauptlink')
       
       for item in all_tooltips:
           item = item.find('a', class_='spielprofil_tooltip')
           if item:
               print(item['href']) #, item.text)
           
       #print(dfs[1])
       #print(dfs[1].iloc[0, :])

   except ImportError:
       print(' ImportError')
    
   except ValueError:
       print(' ValueError')
    
   except AttributeError:
       print(' AttributeError') 

# --- main --

response = get_response('https://www.transfermarkt.de/tsg-1899-hoffenheim/kader/verein/533/saison_id/2019/plus/1')
scraping_kader(response)
```

Result

```
/oliver-baumann/profil/spieler/55089
/philipp-pentke/profil/spieler/8246
/luca-philipp/profil/spieler/432671
/stefan-posch/profil/spieler/223974
/kevin-vogt/profil/spieler/84435
/benjamin-hubner/profil/spieler/52348
/kevin-akpoguma/profil/spieler/160241
/kasim-adams/profil/spieler/263801
/ermin-bicakcic/profil/spieler/51676
/havard-nordtveit/profil/spieler/42234
/melayro-bogarde/profil/spieler/476915
/konstantinos-stafylidis/profil/spieler/148967
/pavel-kaderabek/profil/spieler/143798
/joshua-brenet/profil/spieler/207006
/florian-grillitsch/profil/spieler/195736
/diadie-samassekou/profil/spieler/315604
/dennis-geiger/profil/spieler/251309
/ilay-elmkies/profil/spieler/443752
/christoph-baumgartner/profil/spieler/324278
/mijat-gacinovic/profil/spieler/215864
/jacob-bruun-larsen/profil/spieler/293281
/sargis-adamyan/profil/spieler/125614
/felipe-pires/profil/spieler/327911
/robert-skov/profil/spieler/270393
/ihlas-bebou/profil/spieler/237164
/andrej-kramaric/profil/spieler/46580
/ishak-belfodil/profil/spieler/111039
/munas-dabbur/profil/spieler/145866
/klauss/profil/spieler/498862
/maximilian-beier/profil/spieler/578392
```

Answer (score -1):

That helps me.

I have now copied the table with pandas and replaced the column with the name with the link from your BS4 code. Works!

Comment: This isn't an answer, you should delete this and accept the answer by @furas by clicking on check mark next to vote button.